# Implement Pagination for facebook friendslist using Facebook sdk 3.0.1 Android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to get the Facebook friends page by page.Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

The best way to implement pagination:
when you get first response, retrieve the next page Request object form the Response object. Then execute that request when you want to get next page data

`Response response = yourFirstRequest.executeAndWait();
//getRequestForPagedResults() returns null if there is no more paging, you can get previous page request with parameter PagingDirection.PREVIOUS
Request nextPageRequest = response.getRequestForPagedResults(PagingDirection.NEXT);`

//and after when you want next page info

`nextPageRequest.executeAndWait();`

Answer (score 2):

try this in facebook graph api

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?limit=1

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("limit",  "1");
    Request tagRequest = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), me/friends, params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        //here you can get your friends in json data. and also "paging" with "next" tag.
    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
    JSONObject jsonObject = graphObject.getInnerJSONObject();
        String next = jsonObject.getJSONObject("paging").getString("next");
}
//for next friend
// before using next remove the graph api path from it. i.e  "https://graph.facebook.com/"
    Request.executeGraphPathRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(), next, new Request.Callback() {

    @Override
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: facebook graph api gives "paging" as a tag. e.g "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/583979919/friends?limit=5000&offset=5000&__after_id=100005879198439"}, here you can set limit, and remaining items you can get by hitting the above request. not forget to remove "https://graph.facebook.com" from the request because facebook sdk paste this url itself as graph api path. I am editing my answer for more detail.

Comment: Requirement changed so I have not tried this solution.Thank you for your help.