# Android: How to fetch significant amounts of data from Facebook in order

Tags: android, facebook

I want to get my wall posts, which of course are many, and I want to fetch them chunk by chunk in order to avoid a long time waiting (Let's say limit : 10 at a time), how can I accomplish this?

I use the below code to fetch first 10 posts, **but later and if there is a need to**, I want to fetch the next / following 10 posts, and so on.

```
public void getMeWatchedWantsToWatch()
{
    String pods = "/me/feed";
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("limit", "10");

    new Request(session, pods, params, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback()
    {
        public void onCompleted(Response response)
        {

        }
    }
    ).executeAsync();
}
```

Thank you :)

Edit 1:

For sorry when I used paging using

```
new Request().newGraphPathRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), mNextPageURL, new Request.Callback()
```

I came across an error in the response

> (#100) Tried accessing nonexisting field (data) on node type (URL)

and (data) is the field I specified in the first request which worked correctly and I fetched both my data and the paging url from, so what am I missing here! –  Astrount 1 min ago

Edit 2:

I finally found the source of the problem in my paging request, I must remove "https://graph.facebook.com/" from the paging "next" value before I send it in my request:https://stackoverflow.com/a/16836208/749796 and of course I must specify the same "fields:id, name, etc." in the paging "next" request as in my first request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to implement is paging, search for the paging links in the result and make an API call to the "next" link to get the next batch: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#paging

Btw, i assume you are using `read_stream`, so you may want to read this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

`read_stream` will not get approved for Android Apps. You can try using the `user_status` permission and call `/me/statuses` instead, only the friend posts on your wall are not included that way.

Comment: Thank you for both the paging solution (I'll work on testing it right away) and for the read_stream advice :)

Comment: For sorry when I used paging using new Request().newGraphPathRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), mNextPageURL, new Request.Callback() I came across an error (#100)  Tried accessing nonexisting field (data) on node type (URL), and (data) is the field I specified in the first request which worked correctly and I fetched the paging url from, so what I'm missing here!

Comment: I finally found the source of the problem in my paging request, I must remove "https://graph.facebook.com/" from the paging "next" value before I send it in my request:http://stackoverflow.com/a/16836208/749796